# I am importing a module from home.module import contacts but its showing error no module named home

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWoZ.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87dIY.jpg)

So what can I do here cause I have tried everything but nothing happened please help

pip install home is also showing error so that's a big problem
kindly help

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Please do not post pictures of your code or errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try in you VS Code: `Pip install home`. After that you can import the module in your python file and use it.

Comment: Pip install home is also showing error

Comment: What is the error that it gives?